# How to perform data validation for CAS numbers in Excel worksheets without using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, validation

Is there a way to validate the input of [CAS numbers](https://www.cas.org/support/documentation/chemical-substances/checkdig) in Excel worksheets without using ANY VBA code AND without using cells other than the one where the data is stored?

As you can see in the link the checksum of CAS numbers consists of several steps where each digit is identified, multiplied and summed before a checksum is finally performed.

Besides this checksum there is a second condition, namely that all CAS numbers must be 50-00-0 or higher.

Cramming all the operations required into the 255 character limit for the Custom Data validation formula box appears impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to validate the CAS number format in Excel worksheets without using any VBA code or any extra cells.

The solution is as follows:

First, define the data format of the cell(s) you use as "0-00-0".
[image: CAS Number Format]
This will ensure the correct display of the CAS numbers, while the stored value is a number, which is easier to use for a checksum than a text string.

Second, select the cell(s) you want to use (In this example I use cell B5) and copy/paste the following formula into the Custom formula box (Data → Data Validation):

=AND(MOD(INT(MOD(B5/10,10))*1+INT(MOD(B5/100,10))*2+INT(MOD(B5/1e3,10))*3+INT(MOD(B5/1e4,10))*4+INT(MOD(B5/1e5,10))*5+INT(MOD(B5/1e6,10))*6+INT(MOD(B5/1e7,10))*7+INT(MOD(B5/1e8,10))*8+INT(MOD(B5/1e9,10))*9,10)=MOD(B5,10),B5>=5e4)=TRUE

[image: CAS Data Validation]

This formula consists of 234 characters and will easily fit. It is only possible to **directly** input (type or copy/paste) the correct formula for cells in the ranges A1:ZZ9 & A10:Z99. Cells outside theses ranges require a formula of at least 256 characters (due to the longer cell references), which will not fit.

It is however still possible to use the data validation outside of these ranges. Just copy/paste the cell to any location in the worksheet. The data validation is copied along and will still work. The below (352 character!) formula is what I copied back out from the Custom data validation formula box of cell XFD1048576.

=AND(MOD(INT(MOD(XFD1048576/10,10))*1+INT(MOD(XFD1048576/100,10))*2+INT(MOD(XFD1048576/1000,10))*3+INT(MOD(XFD1048576/10000,10))*4+INT(MOD(XFD1048576/100000,10))*5+INT(MOD(XFD1048576/1000000,10))*6+INT(MOD(XFD1048576/10000000,10))*7+INT(MOD(XFD1048576/100000000,10))*8+INT(MOD(XFD1048576/1000000000,10))*9,10)=MOD(XFD1048576,10),XFD1048576>=50000)=TRUE

The data validation of this cell worked correctly as you can see below when I tried to input a non-integer value.

[image: Error for cell XFD1048576]

At some point in the future CAS will need to add an 11th digit to the CAS number format (because they will run out of numbers). When that happens an additional 27 characters are required to perform the data validation. This will not fit within the 255 character limit. So, if anybody has any suggestions how to shorten the formula even further that would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `=AND(MOD(SUM(INT(MOD(B5/10^ROW($1:$9),10))*ROW($1:$9)),10)=MOD(B5,10),B5>50000)` entered as an array formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.  EDIT - that leaves some room for Ron's points....

Comment: According to what I read, the definition also includes checking that the format is correct, and that there are no more than ten digits.  Your routine would return as valid, for example `1000597887122`

Comment: Ah - that's a good question - I don't know....  Edit - seems you can...

Comment: @TimWilliams Yours works OK, but I've tried with a more complex array formula and was not able to do get it to work, even when it worked OK in a cell.  Maybe because of Named functions?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - hard to say without knowing exactly what you tried.

Comment: @TimWilliams Oh, I know that.  And if I can't figure it out, I'll probably post a question.  Thanks.

Comment: @TimWilliams Very nice!! I tried it and it works. Minor detail about the minimum of the allowed range is that it's **>=** 50000, not **>** 50000. With: `=AND(MOD(SUM(INT(MOD(B6/10^ROW($1:$9),10))*ROW($1:$9)),10)=MOD(B6,10),B6>=50000,B6<=9999999995)` all bases should be covered.